# UIPicker EXC_BAD_ACCESS after repeated usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i populate uipicker's datasource from array built with sqlite database stored data. everythiongs works fine.. for a little while. after 6-7 spinnings, the picker freeze, and I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. debugger indicates the program stopped in the main () function.

so, how could this happen? working for a while, and then, suddenly exit like that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your application, you have over-released an object.  When the application tries to access it again, very likely to release it (from an autorelease pool), it crashes.  The problem may be completely unrelated to your picker.

Suggestion: try adding `NSZombieEnabled YES` to your executable's environment variables.